# cython error by python import

Tags: python, c++, cython

I’m making an C++ class to manage the communication with a device (SPI). The idea is to use this C++ class on an Arduino and a Raspberry Pi. This way I need to make this class only once.

I will use the class on the Arduino (this is no problem).
I also want to use it on my Raspberry Pi together with python. (Here is the problem)

I already made a test class (Rectangle) to use it on both. This one was successful :)

Now I stumble across a problem with my real class.

My idea was to make a `namespace` with 2 classes inside (one `public`, one `private`). The `public` one to manage the communication of the device. The `private` one to manage the SPI bus needed for the device.

Now I want to make the SPI class with the bcm2835 class from mikem, this is where I get an error. (http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/).

***The next files I made (I know, it’s still public):***
*Device.h*

```
namespace device {
    class Spi {
        public:
            int speed, modus;
            Spi(int speed, int modus);
            ~Spi();
            void openSpi();
            void closeSpi();
            void writeSpi(int dataToWrite);
            int readSpi();
    };
}
```

*Device.cpp*

```
#include "Device.h"
#include “bcm2835.h”
#include <iostream>

using namespace device;

//###############################################################################################
//***********************************************************************************************
//      Constructors:
//                      Default constructor: speed = 1MHz, modus = 0
//                      Specific constructor: speed = var(int), modus = var(int)
//***********************************************************************************************
//Specific
Spi::Spi(int speed, int modus) {
    speed = speed;
    modus = modus;
}

//Default
Spi::~Spi() {
}
//###############################################################################################

void Spi::openSpi() {
    if (!bcm2835_init())
    {
      std::cout<< "bcm2835_init failed." ;
      //return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "SPI is open.";
}

void Spi::closeSpi()
{
    std::cout << "SPI is closed.";
}

void Spi::writeSpi(int dataToWrite) {
    std::cout << "SPI write: " << dataToWrite;
}

int Spi::readSpi() {
    return 0;
}
```

*dev.pyx*

```
cdef extern from "Device.h" namespace "device":
    cdef cppclass Spi:
        Spi(int, int) except +
        int speed, modus
        void openSpi()
        void closeSpi()
        void writeSpi(int)
        int readSpi()

cdef class PySpi:
    cdef Spi *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, int speed, int modus):
        self.thisptr = new Spi(speed, modus)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def openSpi(self):
        self.thisptr.openSpi()
    def closeSpi(self):
        self.thisptr.closeSpi()
    def writeSpi(self, data):
        self.thisptr.writeSpi(data)
    def readSpi(self):
        return self.thisptr.readSpi()
```

*setup.py*

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
        "dev",
        sources=["dev.pyx","Device.cpp"],
        language="c++",
    )))
```

I get no errors while building, but when I do “import dev” inside python. I get the error:

> undefined symbol: bcm2835_init

Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`bcm2835_init` is presumably in "bcm2835.cpp" so you need to add that to `sources` in "setup.py"

```
sources=["dev.pyx","Device.cpp","bcm2835.cpp"]
```

Alternatively, if you have a bcm2835 library already compiled you might want to link to it by adding to "setup.py"

```
libraries = ["bcm2835"]
```

You're getting the error because it you call the function (in "Device.cpp") but never provide a definition of the function.